# Disable reformatting code when saving files

Tags: ide, formatting, intellij-idea

I made a small change to an old java file in IntelliJ and when I save the file the IDE automatically reformats all the code. Normally this would be preferable, however it seems almost every line has unnecessary white space that gets cleaned up. Now it appears the entire file was modified even though I only made a small fix. This will make looking at the significant changes in VCS more difficult.

Is there a way to disable code reformatting when a file gets saved? So far I haven't had any luck finding the setting in the Project Settings dialog. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 9.0.2

Alternatively I could perform the reformat, commit the changes, and then make my modification but I feel that this will end up happening a lot and I don't want to impose my formatting preferences on code owned by other groups.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Settings | Editor | General > Other | **Strip trailing spaces on Save** -> None.

---

*Updated for IntelliJ Idea 2021+*

Settings | Editor | General > On Save | **Remove trailing spaces on: <...>** -> None.

Comment: Am I crazy or does this stop only a specific kind of reformatting, not _all_ reformatting?

Comment: In IntelliJ 14.1.5 (build 141.2735) setting this parameter has no effect, when I save the file IntelliJ continue to remove indent in all empty lines...then it appears that the entire was modified (i tried to set "keep indent in empty lines" with no success)

Comment: Does anyone have any updates on this issue for the latest versions?

Comment: @AttitudeL check that you are not using EditorConfig which may override IDE behavior. Some third-party formatter plug-ins can also affect it.

Comment: In my case, `trim_trailing_whitespace` in `.editorconfig` caused unexpected behavior, just on **Save**! *Opposite of the correct behavior of **Reformat** action (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`L`)*, the IDEA removes **"indents on empty lines"** when I save the file!!! (This is just when I set this option in `.editorconfig`). I use Intellij IDEA 2021.1.1 (Ultimate Edition) and saw it in Javascript.

Comment: another problem is that it can only be configured workspace-wide and not project-wide

Answer (score 9):

Preferences -> Tools -> Actions on save -> uncheck "Reformat Code"

Comment: It is unchecked but IDE still reformats. Any solutions?

Comment: This did it for me...thanks. nit: in my version of pycharm(2022.3.2) the preferences is called "settings"

Answer (score 4):

You can add these comments to make it temporarily disable formatting on the file, or a specific function:

```
// @formatter:off
```

If you want one section to remain, you can also add this:

```
// @formatter:on
```

#### [IntelliJ Documentation Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#exclude_part_of_code)

If `@formatter:off` is not working, you can enable it in preferences:

[image: In IntelliJ Preferences, under Code Style, General, Formatter Control there is a checkbox "Enable formatter markers in comments"]

Comment: But then it's completely off, and I can't manually reformat a section of code.

Answer (score 4):

Settings > Tools > Actions on save > first line with checkbox "Reformat code"

> change "Whole file" to "Changed lines"

As it advertise only the modified lines will be affected by formatting on save.

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions (at least WebStorm 2018), `Ctrl + S` is bound to a save Macro that has a reformat code action followed by save.

You can remove this reformat with `Ctrl + Shift + A` search for `Macro` then modify the `save` one.

Edit | Macros | Edit Macros | save | - on the Action: Reformat...

Answer (score 2):

Today in 2020 IDEA is silently formatting HTML before commit, which might break your web pages appearance. To disable that unselect this checkbox:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 2023, the only thing that worked for me was going to `Settings > Editor > Code Style > Formatter tab` and setting the required patterns in the `Do not format` field.

[image: IntelliJ Do not format setting]