# Indent blank lines (IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation

I'd like to set the IDEA formatter to keep indentations on blank lines. Currently when I reformat my source files, it strips all indents on blank lines.

I could not find anything on Google nor could I find a setting in the formatter.

Comment: I'm confused, my IntelliJ does this already, I don't recall changing anything to make it do so. Entirely possibly I'm just not understanding your question though.

Comment: Could you indicate where the indent is set to currently? I had assumed you meant it had no indentation, and when to location 0 on the line. However it occurs to me you may be seeing the opposite, the ability to put the cursor beyond the typed space. I'll give an answer assuming this is true.

Comment: When I hit Ctrl+Shift+W (my customized keymap to reformat source files), it completely removes all the indentations from blank lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The IntelliJ IDEA formatter does not indent blank lines and does not provide any option to do so.

Comment: It seems like it. I have this "OCD" thing where I must have indented blank lines. I'll see if I could suggest this as a feature request to the devs.

Comment: You could, but it's unlikely to be implemented. This contradicts most of the existing code style guides and does not fit well with the architecture of the IntelliJ IDEA formatting engine.

Comment: This is a major bug.  We don't care if the file is actually saved with the blank lines having tabs to the correct indent, but when we click on a blank line the insertion carat should be placed at the correct indenting level for insertion into that method/class/whatever.  The way it is set up, when we click on a blank line, even one that previously had the correct number of tabs for indents, the carat is placed at the far left beginning of the line.  In 99% of the cases this is egregiously wrong.

Comment: Good luck to get this fixed in IJ.

Answer (score 15):

You can't make IntelliJ IDEA *add* indentation to blank lines, but you *can* prevent it from removing them, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2978824/1291990) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2977324/1291990).

Settings | Editor | **Strip trailing spaces on Save** -> None.

Comment: I wish `Only non-blank lines` was an option.

Answer (score 1):

Though I can't seem to make it work as of IntelliJ 14.0.3, there does seem to be an option for this: [Keep indents on empty lines](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-style-java.html#keep_indents_on_empty_lines).

Comment: Hoorah! This was just recently added it seems!

Answer (score 0):

Try this option: File->Settings->Editor->CodeStyle. Find and enable checkbox "Keep indents on empty lines" there .
(available on my intellij idea 14.0.2)

screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYahU.png

Comment: I can not see this option on Rider