# pycharm displays code differently to how its saved and showed by other text editors (... sometimes)

Tags: python, pycharm

It is odd.
For some scripts (but not all) pycharm changes the display of code compared to the actual text-file contents.

[image]

As you can see in the picture: There are additional whitespaces around the equal signs aving been cut from pycharms view and also pycharm adds these strange single-whitespaced indentations to some of the dict-keys.
I have no idea what pycharm-"feature" is at play here to turn it off.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable reformatting code when saving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977324/disable-reformatting-code-when-saving-files)

Comment: no it sadly does not since pycharm does not save these changes ... they are visual only

Answer (score 0):

OK, took me a while but i figured the cause.

It is called the reader mode of pycharm.
It applies to "library" and "read-only" files.
I wasn't aware that my scripts qualify as such and still don't know why.

However the reader mode has some fancy options regarding the rendering.
One can either turn off these fancy options or the entire reader mode in settings->Editor->Reader Mode